# PHP sort - sort multidimensional array by unix timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [uid] => 54915a9f4f26e
            [unixtimestamp] => 1408210200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [uid] => 54915a9f519a2
            [unixtimestamp] => 1408815000
        )

)
```

This is my array, I want to sort them by unixtimestamps orded.

How can I tell PHP sort function that I want to sort the specific unixtimestamp element?

```
sort($myarray); // how to tell sort by unixtimestamp?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
  return $a['unixtimestamp'] - $b['unixtimestamp'];
}

usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```

Where $myArray is your array